# Dynamically add blob data to MediaSource and display on video element

Tags: javascript, video

The client receives Blobs of data, which represent a certain part of the stream that needs to be display (frame, group of frames, etc). The client mediaplayer should display the received data without waiting for the stream to complete. In a bit of a toy example of the intended goal we have the code:

```js
const remoteVideo = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
    
remoteVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
let sourceBuffer = undefined

mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', ()=>{
  sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64000d,mp4a.40.2"');
    
});





if(navigator.mediaDevices != undefined){
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false })
    .then(stream => {
      // remoteVideo.srcObject = stream; -> I am aware this works
      var recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

      recorder.ondataavailable = event => {
        if(sourceBuffer != undefined){
          event.data.arrayBuffer().then((ret) => {
            // DO WHAT WITH THIS DATA?        
          })
                              
        }
      };

      recorder.start(1000); // every t ms save stream
    
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error accessing media devices:', error);
    });
}
```

Obviously, if there was a disinct end time, I could call the end of stream function and play  what is stored in the buffer. But this is not the intended use. I would like to display the Blobs before they have all arrived. Setting the source as the video stream works fine, but these blobs will be received over socket connection.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <body>
        <video id="videoPlayer" width="50%" controls muted="muted" autoplay>
            
        </video>
    </body>
    
    <script src="view.js"></script>
</html>
```